# SSH connection not possible: "Host key verification failed"

Tags: ssh

I was not able to connect to my ssh server. I tried to log in for the first time, but I always received the above mentioned error:

```
The authenticity of host '...' can't be established. 
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:.... Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? 
Host key verification failed.
```

The problem: a known_host file is not existing, because this was my first time connecting.

I could finally resolve this by forcing ssh to not verify the host key with the following command:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No user@adress
```

Then, also the `known_host` file was generated.

Anyway, I would like to know why it was not possible to connect before that. Normally it should work, shouldn't it?
And is it a safety risk to solve this issue like that? As I understood, ssh will never verify the host key now for this specific connection.

Comment: type "yes" if you trust the server... IPs may change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

In my case I was connecting for the first time to my server and I had to type yes and hit enter or I get `The authenticity of host '...' can't be established.  ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:.... Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?  Host key verification failed.`

.